# Software for macOS that allows a user to create multiple transient hover on top windows?

Tags: images

Suggestions please for software for macOS that allows a user to create multiple transient hover on top (rectangular) windows with arbitrary placement and size anywhere on the screen using the mouse?

I want to use this to occlude parts of an image, say in a pdf, prior to taking a screenshot and putting it on the system clipboard, with key binding M-S-C-4, and subsequent pasting for the purpose of creating image occlusion flashcards (outside of using anki).

For instance, this would make it possible to create image occlusion flashcards within Emacs using the screenshot function for use with org-drill.

Instead of this, something like SVG-Edit seems like it would work, however, it doesn't seem to accept images pasted from the system clipboard via paste. As per above, it would also need to allow for copying the occluded result for subsequent paste to another location.

Other approaches similar in spirit are welcome too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link, I wasn't sure where to put it. I'll move it over there.